# How to grab the x, y position of html elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

I have in my html document several div elements with certain css class and want to get x, y position of those elements, thanks in advance.

Comment: get the x,y position in relation to what? the document/window? or its parent?

Comment: get the x,y position in the document.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `getBoundingClientRect`:
http://ejohn.org/blog/getboundingclientrect-is-awesome/

For example:

```
var div = document.getElementById("yourDiv");
var rect = div.getBoundingClientRect();
alert("Coordinates: " + rect.left + "px, " + rect.top + "px");
```

Remember that `getBoundingClientRect` gives the coordinates *relative to the current viewport*, which means that if you want to know the coordinates relative to the `document.body`, you have to add the horizontal and vertical scroll amounts (`document.documentElement.scrollLeft` or `document.body.scrollLeft` for Firefox, and `.scrollTop` of course).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you want to do this http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

Comment: Ah, yes. Good reading if you want to support older clients. That page needs to be updated, though.

Comment: Oh really? Any chance you could explain what's missing there?

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer, `getBoundingClientRect` is a great tool and is supported by all the major browsers. It really simplify things. Not that the old quirksmode.org code doesn't work anymore... It's just slower.

Comment: If I were writing a crossbrowser normalizing library, that solution is the one I would use if Rect wasn't available.

Answer (score 1):

The examples bellow show how to retrieve the ClientRect of an HTML Element

```
# first tag link of this page
document.getElementsByClassName('post-taglist')[0].children[0].getClientRects()[0]
# question div
document.getElementById('question').getClientRects()[0]
```

With it you have acces to right, top, height, width, left and bottom attributes.

Comment: `getClientRects` is overkill, you don't need to know all those. The main reason for getting all the rects is if you want to know the position and the size of lines of text.

Comment: NM. Missed something MaxArt wrote elsewhere.